# YouTubeQuery(..) take too long to show uploaded video

Tags: java, youtube-api, gdata-api

[YouTubeQuery(..)](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos) take too long to show published video. Approximately 24h after upload video. Anyway to speed up this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of time that passed in between when a video is uploaded to YouTube and when it shows up in the YouTube search index can vary. We can't make any guarantees about that.

In general, one common practice that can lead to delays in indexing which you can avoid is uploading the video as unlisted/private and then later flipping it to public when you want the video to be "published". I'm not sure if you're doing that or not, but if you are, try uploading it as public initially instead.